# handlebars registerHelper error: registerHelper is not a function

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, registerhelper

When I try to register a handlebar helper in a node.js file, I get the error message:

> exphbs.registerHelper("hlp", function(num) { TypeError:
>   exphbs.registerHelper is not a function

**Code:**

```
    exphbs.registerHelper("hlp", function(num) {
      num = num.toString();
      return "(" + num + ") ";
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us how you require in the handlebars library? `typeof require('handlebars').registerHelper` returns `function` for me.

Comment: var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

Answer (score 5):

It's important to note you're using `express-handlebars`, which is a plugin to allow using handlebars as a view engine in express. So the object you get from `require('express-handlebars')` won't be a `Handlebars` instance.

The good news is you can still set up helpers. The documentation for the module has [an example](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#helpers):

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
  // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
  helpers: {
    foo: function () { return 'FOO!'; },
    bar: function () { return 'BAR!'; }
  }
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

And if you want to define your helpers in separate files rather than all in this one place (I would):

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
  // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
  helpers: {
    foo: require('./helpers/foo'),
    bar: require('./helpers/bar')
  }
});
```

foo.js:

```
module.exports = function () { return 'FOO!'; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see the point.
shall I define all my helpers used in the project in this place?
Or I will be able to define my helpers separately in different js files?

Comment: You could define them in different files and import them. Updated my answer.

Comment: Sign, npm.  I am apparently using express-hbs not express-handlebars (new to all this, didn't notice there are many of these things).  express-hbs  silently ignores options it doesn't understand, like 'helpers:'

Comment: @Marvin wonderful :D good news - you can still register helpers, but I assume you know that now! https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-hbs#helpers

Comment: @TomJardine-McNamara sure, I get that but I was following THIS post because I was having some issue I didn't understand where the partials were loading and the helpers weren't found so I thought registering the helpers at the "same" (hopefully before) time as I instantiated the engine would help.  As opposed to calling express-hbs.registerHelper.  There may be an issue about loading partials in express-hbs, but it isn't my issue since I did (sorry :-) ) switch to express-handlebars and MY issue went away.